# Server receives GET after POST or PUT request being sent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, httprequest

For some reason when I try to send a `POST` or `PUT` request, the server will receive `GET`. Tried multiple ways of sending the request but the result is always the same.

Here is an example that demonstrates the issue

```
$http.post(baseUrl + '/login',{username:usr,password:psw})
    .then(
        function (response) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            return { status: "OK" };
        },
        function (httpError) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(httpError));
            if(httpError.status == "401"){
                return{ status:"UNAUTH" };
            }
            return { status:"ERR" };
        }
    );

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

always returns GET no matter what. And even the body is empty.

Comment: Did you check the dev tools what request is being sent? Is the request sent by a form submit button?

Comment: I shoul have mentioned it's cordova application.  No, I can't make CORS work no matter what in my browser so I gotta debug the application on a device (as then CORS is not a problem). No, not a form button.

Comment: what server language are you using? probably not checking the request body

Comment: PHP (not author of the API)

Comment: can't receive as `$_POST` in php since angular sends as content type as json by default. Have to change to send form encoded if that is what is expected

Comment: No, that's not the case, the guy correctly parses php input. However the problem seems to be within server configuration as when I try to run the requests against my private server everything works as expected.